# Querying Cassandra by column pairs in a list

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to query Cassandra (3.2) for a any row where a pair of two of the columns should equal any entry in a list of pairs in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset (
    bucket int,
    namespace text,
    name text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket), namespace, name)
);
```

From what I can tell from the `SELECT` [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__ref_select_relation) I should be able to use a `relation` clustering filter. Unfortunately the docs confuse things quite a bit by not properly matching up brackets and parenthesis, but I feel like it tells me the following should work:

```
SELECT namespace, name, data FROM dataset
WHERE id = 12345 AND (namespace, name) IN (namespace1, Peter),(namespace2, Clark)
```

It doesn't however, and neither does:

```
SELECT namespace, name, data FROM dataset
WHERE id = 12345 AND (namespace, name) IN ((namespace1, Peter),(namespace2, Clark))
```

The queries both fail with `...no viable alternative at input...`

How can I write this query correctly?

Comment: Can you please include the table definition as well for `dataset` table?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment under my answer, I also noticed in the official documentation that you can use tuples for `IN` clauses. But this applies only for **clustering columns**. This means that the following example will work, because `namespace` and `name` columns are both **clustering columns** in my table definition (see `PRIMARY KEY` section):

```
CREATE TABLE dataset (
    bucket int,
    namespace text,
    name text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((bucket), namespace, name)
);

SELECT * FROM dataset WHERE bucket = 1 AND (namespace, name) IN (('namespace1', 'Peter'), ('namespace2', 'Clark'));
```

If you change the table definition for the following, the query above will return with an error:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset (
    namespace text,
    name text,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (namespace, name)
);
```

You can read more about clustering columns [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-most-important-thing-to-know-in-cassandra-data-modeling-the-primary-key).

---

Try using the following CQL command

```
SELECT namespace, name, data FROM dataset
WHERE id = 12345 AND namespace = 'dummy' AND name IN ('Peter', 'Clark')
```

[Here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html#reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__selectIN) is the official documentation for `IN` filter

Comment: Thanks. My question was a bit unclear. The `namespace` column doesn't necessarily have the same value for all entries. I've updated my question to reflect this. Unfortunately the `IN` documentation gives me no guidance for this case but when I look at the syntax definition for `SELECT`, it look to me like my use case should be legal